# How to solve a limits problem with perplexing conditions?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

> Let $f$ and $g$ be two functions satisfying $f(x) > g(x)$ for $0 < |x − a| < h$.
>     Suppose $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L$, $\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = M$. Then it is not hard 
>     to show that $M \le L$. Give an example of two functions $f$ and $g$ which 
>     satisfy the above assumptions and for which $L = M$.
>     [Hint: take $a = 0$ and take $f$ and $g$ to be some very simple monomials.]

Hi,

I am working on this problem.

My work out is this: If I consider $f(x) = 1/x^2$ and $g(x) = 1/(2x^2)$ then they satisfy the above conditions. But I am not able to confirm if this will be the right way.

Thanks.

Comment: just one comment. $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is not a monomial. examples of monomials include  $3$, $4x^2$, $5x$, and $2x^100$. They are of the form $ax^n$

Comment: It still follows ax^n where n = -2. Thanks for your try! Better luck next time!

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x)=x^4$. Then for $a=0$ and $h = 1$,
$$
0 <  |x - a| < h \rightarrow f(x) > g(x) 
$$ 
because both are positive, and 
$$
\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{1}{x^2} > 1
$$.

Yet $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}g(x) = 0$.

Comment: I understand most of it but still not getting how L and M are equal i.e the limits are equal?

Comment: L is $\lim_{x-rightarrow 0}f(x)$ which is zero. M is $\lim_{x-rightarrow 0}g(x)$ which is also zero.